# How to add an arrow to menu elements that have children?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recursion, menu

I am trying to add a FontAwesome arrow next to each item in my menu that has children (i.e. I want to indicate that you can click the element to display more data within that category). The menu is populated with json data from an API, and because it is so many nested objects, I decided to use recursion to make it work. But now I am having trouble adding an arrow only to the elements that have more data within it, instead of every single element in the menu.

Does anyone have an idea of how I could change it so the arrow only shows up next to the elements that need it? See below for image

```
class Menu extends React.Component {
  state = {
    devices: [],
    objectKey: null,
    tempKey: []
  };
```

This is where I'm currently adding the arrow...

```
  createMenuLevels = level => {
    const { objectKey } = this.state;
    const levelKeys = Object.entries(level).map(([key, value]) => {
      return (
        <ul key={key}>
          <div onClick={() => this.handleDisplayNextLevel(key)}>{key} <FontAwesome name="angle-right"/> </div>
          {objectKey[key] && this.createMenuLevels(value)}
        </ul>
      );
    });
    return <div>{levelKeys}</div>;
  };

  handleDisplayNextLevel = key => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      objectKey: {
        ...prevState.objectKey,
        [key]: !this.state.objectKey[key]
      }
    }));
  };

  initializeTK = level => {
    Object.entries(level).map(([key, value]) => {
      const newTemp = this.state.tempKey;
      newTemp.push(key);
      this.setState({ tempKey: newTemp });
      this.initializeTK(value);
    });
  };

  initializeOK = () => {
    const { tempKey } = this.state;
    let tempObject = {};
    tempKey.forEach(tempKey => {
      tempObject[tempKey] = true;
    });

    this.setState({ objectKey: tempObject });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get("https://www.ifixit.com/api/2.0/categories").then(response => {
      this.setState({ devices: response.data });
    });
    const { devices } = this.state;
    this.initializeTK(devices);
    this.initializeOK();
    this.setState({ devices });
  }

  render() {
    const { devices } = this.state;
    return <div>{this.createMenuLevels(devices)}</div>;
  }
}
```

This is what it looks like as of right now, but I would like it so items like Necktie and Umbrella don't have arrows, since there is no more data within those items to be shown

[image]

Comment: you need to know if node has childrens, it should be obious while working with tree stuctures

Comment: @xadm sorry I'm very new to Javascript and React so I'm not sure how to do that

Comment: If I understood it correctly you can do something like this: `{Object.keys(objectKey[key]).length && <FontAwesome name="angle-right"/>}`

Comment: @Walk Thank you! I was able to combine your suggestion with vkrn's and get it to work. Much appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check in the map loop from createMenuLevels if the value is empty or not and construct the div based on that information.

```
createMenuLevels = level => {
const { objectKey } = this.state;
const levelKeys = Object.entries(level).map(([key, value]) => {
//check here if childs are included:
var arrow = value ? "<FontAwesome name='angle-right'/>" : "";
return (
    <ul key={key}>
      <div onClick={() => this.handleDisplayNextLevel(key)}>{key} {arrow} </div>
      {objectKey[key] && this.createMenuLevels(value)}
    </ul>
  );
});
return <div>{levelKeys}</div>;
};
```

Instead of just checking if the value is set you could check if it is an array with: `Array.isArray(value)`

Comment: Thank you! I see what you are trying to do, but for some reason it still causes an arrow to be added to the end of every element. The data I'm working with is all objects within objects (no arrays), could this have something to do with it? If so, what change can I make?

Comment: @sarah empty object is still a truthy value. You can use `Object.keys` to check if it has any keys inside.

Comment: @Walk I see yes, thank you! I thought for a moment Object.keys would still be an object but it returns an array.